# Alias to localhost folder

Tags: wamp, alias

I'm trying to setup my WAMP environment again. And I always forget what I have to do to be able to go to "test.dev" insteath of say "localhost/TestProject/index"

What would I have to do to make that work?

Comment: This post should help you remember http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Answer (score 2):

1. Edit `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` as Administrator and add Line

   `127.0.0.1       test.dev`
2. Remove the "#" in `# Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and save and close the `httpd.conf` file.
3. Add in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.x.x\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`  (where x.x is your apache version)

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAdmin webmaster@yourdamin.com
       DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\yourfolder"
       ServerName test.dev
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. Restart Apache